# Drupal view filter by date

Tags: 7, views

I have multiple events, each event can have multiple dates. When an events first end date is passed the event no longer shows, even though future dates are still available.

Current view filter settings:
[image]

I'm not sure what Date:delta(= 0) is but when it's removed, all versions of events are shown. Even though published filter is set it shows all unpublished and drafts.

I've been debugging this for several hours and would appreciate any help.

Comment: When the event is created, is there only one instance of the event content?  I struggled with this also.  I found that I needed to use [Date Repeat Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_repeat_entity) to create multiple unique instances of event content that could possibly have multiple dates.

Comment: Hello @Kiee, any updates on this one?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried such a Views configuration:

- Nodes with a Date field, with multiple dates
- Some nodes have dates only in the past, some only in the future, some in both.
- Configured a Views page with a simple date filter, when value is greater than now

Views filters:

[image]

And Views filters with end-date also works:

[image]

End result:

[image]

It seems to work out of the box, with the simplest setting for me.
Regarding the delta, this is simply an index number for the value in a multiple value field, its position in the list.

Comment: How does this handle start date & end dates rather than just a single date. Also how would it handle mutliple drafts of pages. As I'm experiencing every draft of every event showing even though I have a published filter set.

Comment: Could you share some more details about your setup then? Are you using Workflow? Workbench? Your question seems to grow with every question :-)

Comment: It works with end:date filter also, just tried it.